# AUTO Age Script

Tags: php, date

The issue is the cPanel Error message.

I have a PHP script that auto shows (Sara Smile Is * Years of Age), and I have in (.htaccess) the line (AddType application/x-httpd-php .html), and that runs properly, however cPanel is giving this Error Message: Expected tag name.  Got '?' instead.  (HTML doesn't support processing instructions).

```
<?php
$bday = new DateTime('11.4.2010'); // Persons Date of Birth
$today = new Datetime(date('m.d.y'));
$diff = $today->diff($bday);
printf(' %d ', $diff->y, $diff->m, $diff->d);
printf("\n");
?>
```

Is there a way to auto get (Sara Smile is * Years of Age), Without a cPanel Error message?

Comment: You can try to rename the extension of your file from `html` to `php` and then use `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`

Comment: And the Header of the Page can still be:  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

Comment: You can also add <head> (to specify the encoding) and <body>

Comment: Otay, I Have the <head> & <body> Tags.  Thanks!  :--)

Comment: I Added the Same Script with a Different Birth Date in Another Place on the Page, and that Messed Up the Page.  Any Suggestions?   :--)

Comment: Do not add the same script twice.

Comment: How can I Get Automatic Birth Date Ages Anywhere Per a Page?  :--)

Comment: You can wrap the code in a function taking the birthday as argument and then call the function every time you need to compute the age for a given birthdate.

Comment: I Need to Take a Break.   Can you please Write me a Function Example.  Much Thanks!  :--)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
</head>
<body>
  <?php
    function AutoAge($birthday)
    {
      $today = new DateTime(date('d-m-Y'));
      $bday = new DateTime($birthday); // Persons Date of Birth     
      $diff = $bday->diff($today);
      return $diff->format('%y');
    }
  ?>
  <p>some content here</p>
  <p>Alice has an age of <?php echo AutoAge("11-4-2000"); ?></p>
  <p>other content here</p>
  <p>Bob has an age of <?php echo AutoAge("23-9-2004"); ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

---

## UPDATE

Here is an Easier JavaScript Code:

```js
function AutoAge(birthYear, birthMonth, birthDay)
{
  var birthdate = new Date(birthYear, birthMonth - 1, birthDay);
  var today = new Date();
  return Math.floor((today.getTime() - birthdate.getTime()) 
    / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365);
}

function showBirthday()
{
  var i, elem, items = document.getElementsByClassName('birthday');
  for(i=0; i<items.length; i++)
  {
    elem = items[i];
    elem.innerHTML = AutoAge(elem.dataset.year || 2000, elem.dataset.month || 0, elem.dataset.day || 1) + ' years';
  }
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    </head>
    <body onload="showBirthday()">
      <p>some content here</p>
      <p>Alice has an age of <span class="birthday" data-year="2000" data-month="4" data-day="11"></span></p>
      <p>other content here</p>
      <p>Bob has an age of <span class="birthday" data-year="2004" data-month="9" data-day="23"></span></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Looks Great  Much Thanks!  :--)

Comment: I Have Multiple Div Scrolling Boxes, and the Last Great Suggestion Wasn't a Success.  Any Other Tweaking Suggestions?  :--)

Comment: I Test Added that Script to (AGE.php), and All that Shows is:  some content here

Alice has an age of

Comment: You can test the code on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ - if it works there but not on your server, then the issue is not the code.

Comment: From the Error Log it shows:
[04-Feb-2019 05:08:51 UTC] PHP Warning: DateTime::diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, null given in /home/sy/public_html/AGE.php on line 13
[04-Feb-2019 05:08:51 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on boolean in /home/sy/public_html/AGE.php on line 14

Comment: This means that it does not recognize the format of your birthdays. Try to specify them as DD-MM-YYYY, or look at the manual on http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php for the list of supported formats.

Comment: I Tested the this Code, but that Displays a Blank Page: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
</head>
<body>
  <?php
    $today = new Datetime(date('DD-MM-YYYY'));

    function AutoAge($birthday)
    {
      $bday = new DateTime($birthday); // Persons Date of Birth     
      $diff = $bday->diff($today);
      return $diff->format('%y');
    }
  ?>
  <p>AGE 1:</p>
  <p>SaraJoy has an age of <?php echo AutoAge("11-11-1977"); ?></p>
  <p>AGE 2:</p>
  <p>MoYah has an age of <?php echo AutoAge("07-07-1967"); ?></p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Is there a Easier Javascript Code?  :--)

Comment: For now, I'm Forgetting this.  2019, and this Isn't yet 1 2 3 to do.  :--)

Comment: The Java Script shows the Age after a Delay.  And when I Add a Second Persons Age, it Messes Up the Text After the Script.

Answer (score 1):

I always use this code to calculate in a elegant way the user age and works fine...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>User Age Information</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
  function Calc_Age($myday) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
    $birth = new DateTime($myday);
    $birth->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $today = new DateTime('NOW');
    $today->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $diffs = $today->diff($birth);
    $myage = $diffs->y . ($diffs->y == 1 ? ' year, ' : ' years, ');
    $myage .= $diffs->m . ($diffs->m == 1 ? ' month, ' : ' months, ');
    $myage .= $diffs->d . ($diffs->d == 1 ? ' day, ' : ' days, ');
    $myage .= $diffs->h . ($diffs->h == 1 ? ' hour and ' : ' hours and ');
    $myage .= $diffs->i . ($diffs->i == 1 ? ' minute' : ' minutes');
    return $myage;
  }
?>

<h1>Actual age of Angela</h1>

<p>Angela is <?php echo Calc_Age("1967-01-23 05:00:00"); ?> old</p>

<h1>Actual age of Jhon</h1>

<p>Jhon is <?php echo Calc_Age("1977-04-14 09:10:00"); ?> old</p>

</body>

</html>
```

**Output:**

[image: Age Calc]

---

### Answer with Only Years

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>User Age Information</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
  function Calc_Age($myday) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
    $birth = new DateTime($myday);
    $birth->format('Y-m-d');
    $today = new DateTime('NOW');
    $today->format('Y-m-d');
    $diffs = $today->diff($birth);
    $myage = $diffs->y . ($diffs->y == 1 ? ' year' : ' years');
    return $myage;
  }
?>

<h1>Actual age of Angela</h1>

<p>Angela is <?php echo Calc_Age("1967-01-23"); ?> old</p>

<h1>Actual age of Jhon</h1>

<p>Jhon is <?php echo Calc_Age("1977-04-14"); ?> old</p>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: Age Years Only]

---

### Final Notes

with m-d-Y the php engine cannot calculate the diff dates, to use properly this php class you have to use the standard connotation Y-m-d. This cannot create problem since you know now that you have to call the function with this format

```
Calc_Age("1967-01-23"); // Y-m-d (Year-month-day)
```

Hope this help.

Comment: That might Solve this Without Errors, but I Only want the Age part.  :--)

Comment: Do you need only years?

Comment: Updated my answer, now the script calculates only Years. If you are happy with my answer, please mark my answer as solved and vote up my answer. Glad to help :)

Comment: The Newest PHP Script that Alessandro Posted, Runs Great!  I Tested on Various Browsers, and a Gen 3 iPad.   Thanks!  :--)

Comment: I'm currently Not seeing a Solved Button.  :--)

Comment: I've Tested that Script Before. I'm Used to (m-d-Y)., and was by Mistake Adding Ages via that Format, and that Was Messing It Up. Is there a Way to Change (Y-m-d) to the (m-d-Y) Format? :--)

Comment: [UpVote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq7YZ.png) [Mark Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB3cT.png) as you can see you can vote and mark my answer according to the pictures..

Comment: You cannot use m-d-Y format because it is not a recognized format. See my updated answer.